# Create the simplest Windows 7 sleep keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, sleep

My mother is working on a old PC with Windows 7 where I recommend her to make it sleep at the end of the day instead of shutting it down.

However, since she is old with a bit trembling hand, she can't consistently choose `sleep` option from the small menu shown below without moving the cursor away or choosing wrong option.

[image]

So, my question is: is there a super simple way to create a keyboard shortcut for Windows 7 `sleep` option?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new text file on the desktop. Paste the following text into it:

`Rundll32.exe Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Sleep`

Save the file as `sleep.bat` so it becomes a [batch file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) instead of a text file.
You may have to disable hibernation.

Comment: I hope to avoid a solution needs double-clicking.

Comment: @Diaa select the icon, press Enter?

Comment: I just wonder if there is a possibility of doing it through keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @Diaa There sure is. Which key or key-combo would you like to use?

Comment: I have no preferences; I think the best way is to choose the least common/used button or combo so that it won't conflict with any task now or later.

Comment: @Diaa I posted another answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an Autoit script. Install [autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) first, then create a file with the following contents with the `.au3` file extension (so like `test.au3`)

This example uses the <kbd>s</kbd> key, but you can change that to whatever key (or keycombo) you want (see the left column of the table you'll see if you scroll down a bit on this page): https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm

```
#include<AutoItConstants.au3>

HotKeySet("s", "_Standby")

While 1
    Sleep(10)
WEnd

Func _Standby()
    Shutdown($SD_STANDBY)
EndFunc
```

If you want to autostart it when the computer runs, rightclick the file and chose `Compile script (x86)`. It will create a .exe file (an executable). Then move that executable to the startup folder, usually located at `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Note that Windows 7 no longer receives security updates https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-7-support-ended-on-january-14-2020-b75d4580-2cc7-895a-2c9c-1466d9a53962

Answer (score 1):

Using the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
is usually simpler than using Autoit.

The following AutoHotkey script will shutdown the computer on
<kbd>F12</kbd>:

```
F12::Run, command-line
```

You may use for "command-line":

- [nircmd standby](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)
- [wizmo standby](https://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm)
- [SLEEP.EXE](https://www.gammadyne.com/cmdline.htm#sleep)

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.